# Change setInterval speed in real time

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a `setInterval` which I want to change it's speed in real time:

```
var speed = 150;
var repeat = setInterval(loop, speed);
var print = 0;
function loop(){
    type();
    if (print / 3 === 1) {
        clearInterval(repeat);
        speed = 1000;
        repeat = setInterval(type, speed);
    } 
    if (print / 6 === 1) {
        clearInterval(repeat);
        speed = 150;
        repeat = setInterval(type, speed);
    }
}
function type(){
    console.log(print);
    print++;
}
```

The first `if` changes the speed but the second one isn't, how can I fix it?

Comment: `print / 3 === 1` will be true only when `print` is `3`; it's effectively the same as `print === 3`. Similarly for the second comparison. Note also that the "loop" function only iterates until the interval timer is first cleared (when `print` is `3`) — after that nothing calls `loop()`.

Comment: You're right, I did not notice it, thanks for the help :D